# Dockerfiles COPY does not copy all files and directories

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a very strange problem and connect figure out how to fix it.

Let's say my file structure was like this:

```
# Dockerfile
# └─── app
#      └─── src
#           ├─── main.py
```

And then I add new files and/or replace existing files, such as:

```
# Dockerfile
# └─── app
#      └─── src
#           ├─── main.py
#           ├─── new1.txt
#           ├─── new_folder
#                ├─── new2.txt
```

Let's say the Dockerfiles looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.7.9
WORKDIR /code
COPY app/src/ /src
CMD [ "python", "-u", "./src/main.py" ]
```

I am executing:

```
docker build .
```

And also tried:

```
docker build --no-cache .
```

When I first built the image, it worked fine and copied the content as expected.
From that point on, new version of 'main.py', new files in the folder 'src' and new folders in 'src' are not copied anymore.

Comment: How are you running the container?  How are you verifying what's in the container?

Comment: @titonior, Could you please share the output of `docker build .` and `docker build --no-cache .` , so that it would be clear what is happening at the time of image creation.

Comment: There's a bug in your Dockerfile: you should write `COPY app/src /code/src/`, not `COPY app/src/ /src`; otherwise `./src/main.py` (last line) can't be found in the current working directory (which is `/code`).